# Wordpress numeric (yearly) page names / disable yearly archives

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, slug

I need to achieve page structures on website that is 
`http://pagename.example/2017`, `http://pagename.example/2018` .. etc

Now wordpress rename my page slugs to `2017-2`, `2018-2` because WP use those numbers as Yearly archives - I dont need them.

Is any way, trick, hack how to disable WP Yearly/days archives and allow me to create pages with slugs as in examples ? (2014,2015,2016 .... ) ?

Comment: Do you need the pages with those year names to exist? Or would it be enough to simply create rewrite rule based archives in their place so that the URL structure remains the same? What kind of stuff appears on those pages?

Comment: Thats a real answer!

Comment: Actually - Yes I need those pages, because they have some custom content ...

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of solution but it worked.
I just use plugin called **"Allow Numeric Slugs"** https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/allow-numeric-stubs/

It went out it also allow me to create pages as I need `http://pagename.example/2018` etc...

I don't investigated how it work, but it worked for me :)